# Templates: accessing nested fields of slice of structs

Tags: go, go-templates

I would like to output `slice[0].type` using go templates. While printing works:

```
{{ index .Slice 0 | printf "%+v" }} // {Type:api.Meter ShortType:Meter VarName:meter}
```

printing the field doesn't:

```
{{ index .Slice 0 | .Type }} // template: gen:43:26: executing "gen" at <.Type>: can't evaluate field Type in type struct { API string; Package string; Function string; BaseTypes []main.baseType; Types map[string]main.typeStruct; Combinations [][]string }
```

The error message indicates that the outer loops fields are evaluated, not the result of the `index` call.

What is the correct syntax to access nested fields of slices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`printf` is a builtin template function. When you chain `index .Slice 0` into `printf`, the value is passed as the last argument to `printf`. Accessing the `Type` field is not a function call, you can't chain into that. `.Type` in the chain will be evaluated on the current "dot", chaining does not change the dot.

Group the slicing expression using parenthesis, then apply the field selector:

```
{{ (index .Slice 0).Type }}
```

Example testing it:

```
type Foo struct {
    Type string
}

t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{ (index .Slice 0).Type }}`))

params := map[string]interface{}{
    "Slice": []Foo{{Type: "Bar"}},
}

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0Uno9BePRMi)):

```
Bar
```

Comment: Could you kindly add why the pipe operator shouldn‘t work here? Grateful for the solution but it doesn‘t click why my approach is flawed.

Comment: See edited answer.